# Level sets of a Wiener process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Assume we have a Wiener process $W$ starting at $W_0=0$. What can one tell about the Lebesgue measure of "level sets" $A_y = \{t>0; W_t=y\}, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

I actually need to estimate these probabilities (even more precisely, just determine whether they are zero or positive) for a different process, governed by a certain SDE with a drift and values only on $[0,1]$, but this would be a good start. Obviously, $\mathbb{P}[W_t=y]=0$ for any fixed $t>0$. But I'm not quite sure how to move from here to the whole path. The Wiener process should visit any point infinitely often, but the questions is whether the infinity here is big enough to make the probability positive.

Thanks for comments, hints or links to relevant books/articles.

Comment: You mean, their Lebesgue measure? They are almost surely zero, for every y.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, the Lebesgue measure. Thanks! How would one go about proving that? I would like to have the same result for the SDE I mentioned. So I need to check whether the drift and the finite boundaries cause problems or not.

Comment: $E(\int_0^{+\infty}1_{W_t =y}dt) = \int_0^{+\infty}E(1_{W_t =y})dt = 0$

Comment: Wow, I suspected it to be easy, but not this much. Maybe I should have tried thinking about it myself first. Thanks anyway. Then it seems the drift and the finite boundaries are not going to have an effect on this and it holds for my SDE as well. That helps a lot. I wish I could mark something as an accepted answer, but this way I can only give reputation for the comments. Thanks.

Comment: "Maybe I should have tried thinking about it myself first." Maybe, indeed.